# Go Graphql authentication design

Tags: go, graphql, jwt

I am creating a graphql api in go using gqlgen, gorm and chi.
I've successfully created the base logic with the schemas and resolver, but I have issues with the authentication.
I want to use JWT to authenticate users.

I get that I have to use middleware to achieve this, but in the examples I saw, the middleware allows access to unauthanticated users (to permit them to reach login and createUser queries), and so it only blocks faulting JWT.
Then they perform a check on the context (where they stored the JWT) in EACH resolver function to see if the user is authenticated.

And here is my question: is there a better way than having to call an `isAuthenticated` function at the beginning of each of the resolver functions?

I also thought about creating a second enpoint (`/login`), which only handles the `login` and `createUser` queries, but it kind of ruins the whole point of graphql.

Answer (score 3):

Using a middleware and a `isAuthenticated` method in each resolver function is indeed the design I would recommend.

Usually when you have an API you want to handle authentication (user exist or not) and authorization (Does user have the right to access this data?). Authorization should be handled at the resolver level for each function.
So rather than the `isAuthenticated()` method, I use a `userFromContext()` that returns user info with level of authorization.